# App Launching from an activity besides the main

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to launch my app from an activity besides the main but I keep getting this error

**Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity**

Here is my code from my Android Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".SignIn">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SignIn" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="wasiqsiddiqui.studygroup.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove intent filter from .MainActivity and replace .SignIn with .MAIN action.

```
<activity android:name=".SignIn">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: @user5960138 anytime :)

Answer (score 4):

Your MainActivity should written like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I do not want to launch the app from the main activity. I want to launch it from the Sign In activity. Will this code affect it?

Comment: then add this flter to sign in avctivity

Comment: If your launcher is SigninActivity than replace Signin intent filters **<action android:name="android.intent.action.SignIn" />** with 
**<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />**